# Divide all columns by a chosen column using mutate_all

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample data frame that looks like this (my full dataframe has "d" plus 57 elements):

```
d <- seq(0, 100, 0.5) 
Fe <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Ca <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Zr <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Ti <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Al <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
example <- data.frame(d, Fe, Ca, Zr, Ti, Al)
Ratio_Elements <- c("Fe", "Ti", "Zr", "d") #this subset of the 
dataframe is user defined
Detrital_Divisor <- "Zr"
```

The Detrital_Divisor can change based on the user input but will always be a column in the "example" dataframe. I would like to divide all the remaining columns by the Detrital_Divisor column, preferably using a pipe. Right now I have:

```
Example_Ratio <- example %>%
select (Ratio_Elements) #to subset to the user selected elements
mutate_all(./Detrital_Divisor)
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in Ops.data.frame(., Detrital_Divisor) : 
  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames.
```

I have also tried:

```
Example_Ratio <- example %>%
select (Ratio_Elements)
sweep(., Detrital_Divisor, MARGIN = 1, '/')
```

based on similar questions that have been asked on this forum but I just can't get it to work. I get the error

```
    `Error in Ops.data.frame(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)),  : 
  list of length 206340 not meaningful.`
```

I know this question is somewhat repetitive but the other answers I have found are not working in my situation. My entire data frame has 57 elements so writing code to divide each column individually would be very long.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Sorry slight formatting error. In the first code block the comment should include the text on the line immediately below i.e. the whole comment should read #this subset of the dataframe is user defined

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Something like this perhaps:

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- seq(0, 100, 0.5) 
Fe <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Ca <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Zr <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Ti <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
Al <- runif(201, min = 0, max = 1000) 
example <- data.frame(d, Fe, Ca, Zr, Ti, Al)
Ratio_Elements <- c("Fe", "Ti", "Zr", "d") #this subset of the 

Example_Ratio <- example %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-Zr), funs(. / Zr)) %>%
  select(Ratio_Elements)
```

I know you said you'd like to see a `mutate_all` solution, but I guess you don't want to divide `Zr` by itself?

In this case `mutate_at` is more helpful, otherwise you can do `mutate(across(everything(), ~ . / Zr))`.

If you want to keep the mentioned vector, there are at least two options.

Either converting it to name via `as.symbol` and using `!!` as shown below:

```
Detrital_Divisor <- as.symbol("Zr")

Example_Ratio <- example %>%
  mutate(across(-Detrital_Divisor, ~ . / !! Detrital_Divisor)) %>%
  select(all_of(Ratio_Elements))
```

Or using `.data` pronoun and keeping it as character/plain string:

```
Detrital_Divisor <- "Zr"

Example_Ratio <- example %>%
  mutate(across(-Detrital_Divisor, ~ . / .data[[Detrital_Divisor]])) %>%
  select(all_of(Ratio_Elements))
```

---

**dplyr versions < 1.0.0**

With `dplyr` versions below `1.0.0` you cannot use `across`. However, both in `0.8` and `1.0` you can do:

```
Detrital_Divisor <- as.symbol("Zr")

Example_Ratio <- example %>%
  mutate_at(vars(- !! Detrital_Divisor), ~ . / !! Detrital_Divisor) %>%
  select(Ratio_Elements)
```

On the other hand there's also `list` - useful for mutating in multiple ways or naming the output, e.g.:

```
Example_Ratio <- example %>%
  mutate_at(vars(- !! Detrital_Divisor), list(appended_name = ~ . / !! Detrital_Divisor))
```

With the versions before `0.8.0`, there is `funs` (deprecated since `0.8.0`):

```
Detrital_Divisor <- as.symbol("Zr")

Example_Ratio <- example %>%
  mutate_at(vars(- !! Detrital_Divisor), funs(. / !! Detrital_Divisor)) %>%
  select(Ratio_Elements)
```

Comment: Thanks @arg0naut, that does work. It seems it was just the order I had wrong...do the mutate first and then select. Do you know how I can change the code to use the Detrital_Divisor vector that I had listed above? Something like: `mutate_at(vars(-Detrital_Divisor), funs(. / Detrital_Divisor))`

Comment: Yup, that did it. Out of curiosity, do you know why I can use the select function on that string of characters as I wrote it but to do your operation you set the Detrital_Divisor to as.symbol? Would it be better to set my Ratio_Elements to as.symbol too?

Comment: You can try and see what error you get. Most likely it'll say that you have an unary operator (i.e. a minus sign), and you cannot negate a string, that's why quoting. Setting Ratio_Elements in the same way would make sense if you'd like to exclude those columns. In your current situation I don't see it as needed.

Comment: now that funs() is deprecated, how can this be updated?

Comment: @arg0naut91 is there any one-liner solution after deprecating `funs`? I find it unintuitive to remember the `as.symbol` thing.

Comment: @Jiāgěng not any that I would know of, unfortunately.

Comment: @arg0naut91 You can leave `"Zr"` as a plain string if you use `.data[[]]`. So the code becomes: `example %>% mutate(across(-all_of(Detrital_Divisor), ~./.data[[Detrital_Divisor]])) %>% select(all_of(Ratio_Elements))`

Comment: See the [rlang blog post](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-)

Comment: Indeed you're right, thanks! I'll try to update the post in a less verbose way.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE to answer by @arg0naut91 **(dplyr 1.0.0)**

```
Example_Ratio <- example %>% 
  mutate(across(everything()), . / Zr) %>% 
  select(Ratio_Elements)
```

Comment: You still need to add the tilde ~ I think.